# Select all (CTRL+A) option not present in SWT Text field

Tags: java, swt

I am using an SWT application. I can't select all text in a text box or text area by <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
text.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.stateMask == SWT.CTRL && e.keyCode == 'a') {
            text.selectAll();
            e.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For better readability, I would suggest using "e.keyCode == 'a'" instead. 97 doesn't really mean much when you're reading it.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Addaselectallmenuitemtothecontrol.htm

Answer (score -1):

Ideally as per LAF doco, if you have set the correct look and feel you should get this automatically.

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

If not see what they have done here
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/copy-data-from-ms.shtml

Comment: This only applies to Swing, which is not what is being used here.